# Why are two while() loops causing a crash?

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    int main(){

    char p;
    bool show_cleartext;
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Would you like the output to show your original text? [y/n] \n";
    while(true){
        std::cin >> input;
        if(input == "y"){show_cleartext = true; break;}
        else if(input == "n"){show_cleartext = false; break;}
        else std::cout << "[y/n] ? \n";
    }
    while(true){
        // Promts for 'input' then displays input, reversed
        std::getline(std::cin,input);
        if(input == "quit")break;
        for(int i = 0; i < (input.length()-1)/2; ++i){
            p = input[input.length()-i-1];
            input[input.length()-i-1] = input[i];
            input[i] = p;
        }
        std::cout << input+'\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Each of the while loops by themselves is fine. However including both of them causes the program to crash once it proceeds past the first one i.e. entering 'y' or 'n'.

Comment: My educated guess: in the second loop, `input` is an empty string, `input.length()` is zero, `input.length()-1` wraps around to a very large number, and you access index out of bounds.

Comment: I thought you were correct but initializing input as "asdasd" or something does not help. EDIT: Making the change between the while loops does nothing

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/ESZT28102)

Answer (score 0):

When you ask the user if `input` "quit", the `input` size becomes "" or 0. So basically `input` is an empty string and when you do `input.length()` and it equals 0 it wraps around to a huge huge number and that causes the crash. This is what I got from my debugger and I recommend you use one too.

To fix this remove the `std::getline(std::cin,input);`

That resets the `input` size.

Comment: I tried simply removing `std::getline(std::cin,input);` but it crashes just the same. Your remarks localize the problem to the second while loop but the program runs just fine with only the second loop and the first one removed. Finally 'std::getline(std::cin,input);' is what actually assigns `input` by the user. `cin` does not read past spaces.

Comment: I just discovered that the problem is the second loop when you input just one character. I can proceed from here. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this expression: 
p = input[input.length()-i-1];
 leads to -1 index in input array.
So if you have 0 input you get the error.
Maybe try this:

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <string>

     int main(){

    char p;
    bool show_cleartext;
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Would you like the output to show your original text? [y/n] \n";
    while (true){
        std::cin >> input;
        if (input == "y"){ show_cleartext = true; break; }
        else if (input == "n"){ show_cleartext = false; break; }
        else std::cout << "[y/n] ? \n";
    }
    while (true){
        // Promts for 'input' then displays input, reversed
        std::cout << "Input: ";
        std::cin >> input;
    //  std::getline(std::cin, input);
        if (input == "quit")break;
        for (int i = 0; i < (input.length() - 1) / 2; ++i){         
            if (input.length() != 0)
            {
                p = input[input.length() - i - 1];
                input[input.length() - i - 1] = input[i];
                input[i] = p;
            }                       
        }
        std::cout << input + '\n';

        break;

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the usage of `std::getline(std::cin,input);`. `getline` extracts the characters from `istream` until a delimiter or `\n` is reached. In your case, the istream buffer from the previous `std::cin` contains `\n`. This results into a string of size `0`

Secondly, `input.length()` returns `size_t` which is unsigned integral type. In this case `input.length() - 1` becomes a large number and loop condition evaluates to true. Subsequently, a segmentation fault is received on access of `input[input.length()-i-1];`

To prevent the error, you can replace `std::getline(std::cin,input)` with `std::cin >> input` in the 2nd `while` loop or replace `std::cin >> input` with `std::getline(std::cin,input)` in the first.